# Exposing a SOAP/TCP service to .net 2.0 clients

Tags: c#, wcf

Is it possible to expose a SOAP/TCP service to .net 2.0 clients?

I've successfully exposed it over HTTP protocol, but when I change the service binding to tcp I'm getting the following error when trying to communicate to it from .net 2.0 client: 'The URI prefix is not recognized.'

I've used the URI: net.tcp://localhost:8127/myservice

Comment: No, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1083571/542251)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NET 2.0 is not able to consume `net.tcp` or `wsHttp`, you should use `basicHttpBinding` to consume the service from 2.0 clients. WCF came out with net 3.0